# Can I avoid duplicate styles with Vue.js components?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, sass-loader

I'm new to Vue (and the concept of single file components) and not sure how the CSS is compiled when my app is generated.

I have a pattern library where all the SCSS is compiled for my project so I want to pull this into my components.  I know I can load in the mixins and variables globally, then I intend on handpicking other blocks of sass if they need to be used to style that component.

What I'm worried about is:

***if I keep using the same style definitions in multiple components, will these be duplicated in the compiled css?***

If so. how can that be avoided?  Eg:
*I import the 'headings.scss' in 10 components.  Will there be 10 instances of that 'headings.scss' file in the compiled CSS?*

I hope that makes sense!  Just need some more clarity here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yup there will be duplication. But if you are using vuejs [webpack](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack)  template the production build's css is processed by [cssnano](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) which will discard duplicated css

**note;** only exact duplicates will be discarded.

Comment: Ah that's good to know! If I'm mostly importing .scss then they will be exact duplicates so it seems cssnano is the key. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, cssnano removes duplicates when you build your app for **Production** (npm run build).However, in development mode you still see duplicates.